# Where does the onclick event come from in Spring Faces?

Tags: javascript, spring, jsf

I'm trying to suppress the onclick event which gets added by Spring Faces. This looks like a call to Spring.remoting.submitForm for any link rendered with the ProgressiveCommandLinkRenderer. However it isn't in the response as returned by the server. Instead, there seems to be some javascript on the client-side to change the element from an  into an  and also add this onclick.

Even after searching through Spring.uncompressed.js, Spring.Dojo.uncompressed.js and others, I can't seem to find this javascript, or any reference to Spring.remoting.submitForm other than direct calls (i.e. not via obtrusive javascript onclick handler). Where is this code??

Comment: can you add code example, question is not very readable and clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found that this actually gets added in BaseHtmlTagRenderer as a "render callback". This is added as an inline script fragment which called Spring.addDecoration on the client-side, which in turn modifies the rendered HTML to match what the render callback says.

The Spring javascript implementation of this (without mention of the specific usage by Spring Faces) is detailed here:
http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/ch11s04.html